# $f \in AC[a,b]$ and $g$ continuous, $f'=g$ almost everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, lebesgue-integral

Suppose $f: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is absolutely continuous and $\exists$ function $g$ continuous, $f'=g$ almost everywhere.

I'm trying to prove that $f$ is differentiable everywhere and $f'(x)=g(x)$ for every $x$.

My thought is to use fundamental theorem of calculus for continuous function $g(x)$ and the fact that f is differentiable a.e and $f' \in \mathcal{L}^1[a,b]$, which implies $\int f'=\int g$. I'm quite confused about what to do next because we haven't really studied the fundamental theorem of calculus in Lebesgue measure point of view. Just wondering if my idea is doable.

Comment: It's very much doable. If you define $F(x) = f(a) + \int_a^x g(t)\,dt$, what do you know about $f$ and $F$?

Comment: An absolutely continuous function need not be everywhere differentiable (see $\sqrt[3]x$ at $x = 0$, for instance), but it is almost everywhere differentiable.

Comment: Can we get $F(x)=f(x)$? But seems like that we do not know that $\int_a^x f'(t)dt=f(x)-f(a)$. Could you please elaborate in the answer below? Thanks. @DanielFischer

Comment: But we now have $f'=g$ a.e. @Arthur

Comment: The point is that an absolutely continuous function is the integral of its derivative. That is, $f(x) - f(a) = \int_a^x f'(t)\,dt$. Now the question is what the most suitable way to prove that is. How much background in measure theory have you? Do you know the Radon-Nikodym theorem?

Comment: @DanielFischer Bounded variation, absolutely continuous function and all the way to Banach-Zaretsky Thm. I think we can prove it without invoking FTC because the thing is almost a Riemann integration. Thank you.